# Using Framer Motion in React class components (non-functional)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have a simple animation with **Framer Motion** that works perfectly on **functional component** but doesn't work on **class component**
I am new to Framer Motion and That is my **react** code =>

```
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <>
        <motion.section
          inital={{ width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", opacity: 1 }}>
       
        </motion.section>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, `inital` should be `initial` (missing i after t). Besides that your code is fully functional and framer motion works same with class components as it does with functional (but of course you can't use hooks from framer motion in class components)